# SQL Server, find cross value in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns, sql-server-2017

I need to help for a sql server query. I have to many rows like this and my table has 3 columns like a, b, c.

```
      a          b          c
     ---        ---        ---
    hello      world       10
     hey        you        80
    world      hello       20
     my         day        15
    merhaba    dunya       40
    bugun      nasilsin    75
    dunya      merhaba     20
```

So I want to find cross values in different columns with add c column values. So after the query I want to see that;

```
      a          b          c
     ---        ---        ---
    hello      world       30
     hey        you        80
      my        day        15
    merhaba    dunya       60
     bugun     nasilsin    75
```

Sorry for my bad English, thank you for answers...

Edit: answers don't work. I tried them all. Have you any idea for this solution guys?

Comment: Will you have only 2 rows of such type or many?

Comment: So many rows like this.

Comment: quite don't understand you case for sum u can use . -> select sum(c) from table group by 1=1

Comment: so you want to consider groups where the b column value is equal to a column value and sum up the c columns?

Comment: Yes, I want to grouping where column a value equals column b and column b equals column a with sum up c. I edited my question for more explanatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way of doing this

```
create table t(a varchar(10), b varchar(10), c varchar(10))

insert into t values('hello','world',10)
insert into t values('world','hello',20)

select  min(a) as a
       ,max(b) as b
       ,sum(cast(c as int)) as c
  from t as x
 group by case when a>b then a
            else b
       end
```

Comment: But I have to many rows like this, I editted my question. Thank you for your comment but how can I apply this way for all rows?

Comment: What is your expected result and what did you actually get?

Answer (score 0):

If there are unmatched rows, or "pairs" , then:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(
>    a      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
>   ,b      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
>   ,c      INTEGER  NOT NULL
> );
> INSERT INTO mytable(a,b,c) VALUES ('hello','world',10);
> INSERT INTO mytable(a,b,c) VALUES ('hey','you',80);
> INSERT INTO mytable(a,b,c) VALUES ('world','hello',20);
> INSERT INTO mytable(a,b,c) VALUES ('my','day',15);
> INSERT INTO mytable(a,b,c) VALUES ('merhaba','dunya',40);
> INSERT INTO mytable(a,b,c) VALUES ('bugun','nasilsin',75);
> INSERT INTO mytable(a,b,c) VALUES ('dunya','merhaba',20);
>
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 7 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select t.a, t.b, sum(t.c + coalesce(t2.c,0))
> from mytable t
> left join mytable t2 on t.a = t2.b and t.b = t2.a
> group by  t.a, t.b
>
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> a       | b        | (No column name)
> :------ | :------- | ---------------:
> my      | day      |               15
> merhaba | dunya    |               60
> world   | hello    |               30
> dunya   | merhaba  |               60
> bugun   | nasilsin |               75
> hello   | world    |               30
> hey     | you      |               80
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cdeff89fabd809bc66c109b504a71d8d)*

Comment: `t` and `t2` are 'aliases' - names assigned to the table `mytable` so that the query can do a "self-join"

Comment: Hello sir, thank you again for your comment but I have a problem. Your code is return this table;                           a       | b        | (No column name)
:------ | :------- | ---------------:
my      | day      |               15
merhaba | dunya    |               60
world   | hello    |               30
dunya   | merhaba  |               60
bugun   | nasilsin |               75
hello   | world    |               30
hey     | you      |               80  but we don't want to see "dunya merhaba 60" and "hello word 30" rows. How can solve this?